# Failed at the @angular/cli@8.3.19 postinstall script

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

Hi I can't install the angular cli with `npm install -g @angular/cli@8.3.19`.
I keep getting this :

```
> node ./bin/postinstall/script.js

module.js:549
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/root/.nvm/versions/node/v13.0.1/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/postinstall/script.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:188:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:609:3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @angular/cli@8.3.19 postinstall: `node ./bin/postinstall/script.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @angular/cli@8.3.19 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-11-26T00_10_33_515Z-debug.log
```

Node version : 13.0.1
Npm version : 6.13.1
Ubuntu version : 18.04.2

I also tried without specifying a CLI version.

Answer (score 18):

I tried with this command that I found online :

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@8.3 --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root
```

And it worked.

Comment: worked as magic for me

Answer (score 3):

Try to run with `sudo npm`. On Ubuntu, you need to run with root permission. It depends on how you install node.

```
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli@8.3.19
```

On the other hand, try to install node 12 and LTS versions to have a more secure version.

Hope it helps

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/node: 1: /usr/local/bin/node: ELF: not found
/usr/local/bin/node: 12: /usr/local/bin/node: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")`

Comment: Try to uninstall node 13 and install node version 12 because of node version 13 is unstable.

Answer (score 0):

Try clean your npm cache before `npm cache clean` or `npm cache verify` then `npm install -g @angular/cli@8.3 --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root`

Answer (score 0):

Steps I followed

1. Downgrade node version  using nvm to  v12.3.0
2. Remove `ng` folder from `/root/.nvm/versions/node/v12.3.0/bin`
3. Again do `npm install -g @angular/cli@8.3 --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root`

and it worked

Comment: It worked with ubuntu container