# While updating angular project from 9.1.12 to 10.1.0, It is giving an error

Tags: angular

> An unhandled exception occurred: npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2:
> request has been deprecated, see
> https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142 npm WARN deprecated
> har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
> internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:968

[image]

Comment: See if this works: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59041923/6513921. Replace the Angular CLI version with your desired version number.

Comment: It did not work, In other's laptop with the same CLI version, it did work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove npm cache.

**Run following commands:**

1. sudo npm cache verify
2. sudo rm package-lock.json
3. sudo rm -rf node_modules
4. sudo npm install

If it does not work. remove pc npm cache then run following command.