# Ionic is not working well on server CentOS 7.99 after correct installation

Tags: node.js, angular, linux, ionic-framework, centos

I am getting frustrated because I can't make the approach I am searching for. I want to run an ionic server I've installed node, npm , angular, ionic, Cordova.
what's the error?

```
ionic start todo blank
```

System ask me if I want angular, I select angular, so, the system starts to run commands and it get stuck on

```
npm i --save -E @capacitor/core@latest
```

it gives me an error with post install script, this one specific:

```
> npm i
npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated flatten@1.0.3: flatten is deprecated in favor of utility frameworks such as lodash.
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.6.0: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 does not receive security updates since 2019. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x fewer dependencies
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, whichis known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, whichis known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /root/ion_test/todo/node_modules/@angular/cli
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node ./bin/postinstall/script.js
npm ERR! node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
npm ERR!   throw err;
npm ERR!   ^
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Error: Cannot find module '/root/ion_test/todo/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/postinstall/script.js'
npm ERR!     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
npm ERR!     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
npm ERR!     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
npm ERR!     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
npm ERR!   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
npm ERR!   requireStack: []
npm ERR! }

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-01-28T17_51_13_147Z-debug.log
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess npm.

        npm i exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

Please I need help, the server will be launching this in 7 days, I was wondering how can I solve this error and run ionic start and ionic serve with no errors.

Comment: do you have the angular cli installed on your machine?

Comment: Sorry for the long time answer, yes I do when I go ng v I get the version displayed on terminal

Comment: see if this post helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59041923/failed-at-the-angular-cli8-3-19-postinstall-script

Comment: @SomeStudent it didn't work :S

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63841549/an-unhandled-exception-occurred-cannot-find-module-angular-compiler-cli-with/63841959

Comment: What version of npm, ionic, node and angular are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your Angular install is either borked or outdated, or there's a mismatch between the Angular version and Ionic. Try `npm install -g @angular/cli@latest` and see if that helps. If not, post your Angular version and your package.json.

Comment: Hello Tim, that solution didn't work for me.

Comment: What's your output from `ng v`? What does your package.json look like? Need more info if you want help. See the guidelines for a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: for package.json do you point to the ionic project, I create a blank project with ionic start and it crashes with nom I , because of package.json I guess... also, ng v gives me this output: Angular CLI: 13.2.0 Node: 16.13.2 Package Manager: npm 8.1.2 OS: linux x64, Angular: undefined, @angular-devkit/architect    0.1302.0, @angular-devkit/core  13.2.0,
@angular-devkit/schematics   13.2.0,
@angular/cli                 13.2.0,
@schematics/angular          13.2.0,